# Elaborar un programa que elimine todas las palabras de una cadena de caracteres que tengan delante de ellas una palabra con la consonante “c”

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

```
        Console.Write("ingrese la cadena: ");
        string cadena = Console.ReadLine();`
        
        string palabra="";
        string[] pedazos = cadena.Split(' ');
        int n = pedazos.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            palabra=pedazos[i];
            int n2 = palabra.Length;    
            for (int j = 0; j < n2 ; j++)
            {
                 if (palabra[j]==99)
                 {
                     pedazos[i] = pedazos[i+1];
                 }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1 ; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {1} ", (i + 1), pedazos[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

/*me elimina la palabra que contiene la letra "c" cuando debería eliminarme la anterior a ella por ejemplo: ingreso: "alvaro cabrera flores" y me devuelve "alvaro flores" y debería devolver "cabrera flores"*/

Comment: Debería devolver "cabrera flores" o "alvaro flores"?

Comment: debería devolver "cabrera flores"

Comment: ¿Solo tienes que imprimirla? ¿O debe quedar guardada en algún lugar?

Comment: Y otra cosa esa palabra tiene que empzar con la letra c?

Comment: tengo que eliminar la palabra que esta antes de otra palabra pero si la segunda tiene la letra "c" (alvaro cabrera flores se elimina alvaro y mantiene las otras 2 ) y si fuera alvaro flores cabrera se elimina flores y queda alvaro cabrera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He implementado esta solución:

```
    Console.Write("Ingrese la cadena: ");
    string cadena = Console.ReadLine();

    string palabra="";
    string siguientePalabra = "";
    string[] pedazos = cadena.Split(' ');
    int n = pedazos.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        palabra = pedazos[i];
        siguientePalabra = pedazos[i + 1];

        if (siguientePalabra[0] != 'c') // Condición dada del ejercicio
            Console.Write(palabra + " ");
    }
    Console.Write(pedazos[n - 1]); // Imprimir la última palabra
```

La idea es almacenar la siguiente palabra y revisar si su primer caracter (es decir `siguientePalabra[0]`) es la letra 'c'. Esto ocurre dentro de un solo ciclo.
Por último se imprime la última palabra de `pedazos`, la cual no tiene ninguna restricción puesto que no tiene ninguna palabra luego de ella.

Comment: Gracias!, funciona muy bien